# How to use member function in compare?

Tags: c++, templates, functor

For example, I have a class

```
class A
{
public:
    int Value() const;
};
```

How to use `A::Value()` as a compare in `std::lower_bound` function?

```
std::vector<A> v;
std::lower_bound<v.begin(), v.end(), ???>(v, 1);
```

And how to find the element in `v` with a given `Value`.

```
std::find_if<???, ???>(v.begin(), v.end(), ???); // or use other function
```

Comment: Wait... What?  What are you trying to do with `Value`?

Comment: I simplify my question. It is A::Name(). I want to compare with their string name.

Comment: I see no `Name()` above?

Comment: I change Name() to Value() to intend to simplify the question. But it lose some meaning.

Comment: First of all stop trying to explicitly instantiate templates that are supposed to automatically deduce their argument types. Wait, what are you actually doing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a binary predicate that compares two `A` instances. For example

```
std::lower_bound(v.begin(), 
                 v.end(), 
                 [](const A& lhs, const A& rhs) 
                 { return lhs.Value() < rhs.Value(); });
```

Or, if you don't have C++11 support,

```
bool comp(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
  return lhs.Value() < rhs.Value();
}

std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

As for `find_if`, the principle is similar, except that you need a unary predicate, i.e. a functor that takes a single `A` and returns a `bool`.

Comment: +1 pretty hard to tell what's really being asked, but this is probably the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

And for find_if, you'd need to do something like:

```
A valueToFind;
std::find_if(v.begin(),
             v.end(),
             [valueToFind&](const A& arg)
             { return valueToFind.Value() == arg.Value() });
```

and without c++11,

```
bool isEqual(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
   return lhs.Value() == rhs.Value();
}

A valueToFind;
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(isEqual, valueToFind));
```